# JFreeChart Show all DomainAxis Elements in Graph

Tags: java, jfreechart

How to show all the elements of x axis I added to dataset?

for example my x axis dataset values are

arraylist = {-40,-30,-20,-10,0,10,20,30,40} I would like to show all these values exactly in my x-axis(Domain Axis)

```
    XYPlot xyPlot = chart.getXYPlot();
    NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(); 
    int tick = arraylist.get((arraylist.size()/2)+1);
    xAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(tick));        
    plot.setDomainAxis(xAxis);

    NumberAxis domain = (NumberAxis) xyPlot.getDomainAxis();
    domain.setRange(arraylist.get(0), arraylist.get(offset.size()-1));
```

Here **tick** works only if there is constant increase in domain Axis (like 10 in this example),

arraylist = {-40,-36,-24,0,5,10,20}, how to display these values?